# Is there something in between write-verbose and write-progress that shows that a script is not dead?

Tags: powershell, script

I have a script that can delete files and folders recursively, it has the option to turn on verbosity but sometimes you dont want 100s of thousands of filenames to be written to the host.

In that situation something like every few seconds it writes "x records deleted" to the host using -NoNewLine

i figure maybe this needs to be wrapped into a job or something, but i dont really know how to do that for local scripts, if it was remote id use invoke-command or something

Heres the script to tail-recursively delete things

```
function RecurseFolderDelete {
        Write-Host "* is greedy wildcard"
        Write-Host "? is non greedy wildcard"
        $term= Read-Host -Prompt "enter search term to delete"
        Write-Host "all folders and files with the term '$term' in current directory will be deleted"
                $reply = Read-Host -Prompt "Continue?[y/n]"
if ( $reply -match "[yY]" ) { 
        $verbosity = Read-Host -Prompt "verbose? [y/n]"
if ( $verbosity -match "[yY]" ) { 
       
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "$term" -Directory | remove-item -Recurse -Verbose -Force
}
if ( $verbosity -match "[nN]" ) { 
       
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "$term" -Directory | remove-item -Recurse -Force
}
}
}
```

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862396/powershell-get-childitem-progress-question and see if your solution is available in there.

Comment: @spikey_richie Yep... found something that kinda works

Answer (score 1):

Ok so with the help of @spikey_richie I found the following answer

adding

```
Where-Object { Write-Progress "Deleting  $($_.Fullname)"; $true }
```

and piping the results of the Get-ChildItem to it results in a working method that displays the current folder being worked on, it might need refinement, but Its enough of a start for me to work on.

if you pipe the remove-item to the where-object you get a more frequently updating progress ticker.

new script is this

```
function RecurseFolderDelete {
        Write-Host "* is greedy wildcard"
        Write-Host "? is non greedy wildcard"
        $term= Read-Host -Prompt "enter search term to delete"
        Write-Host "all folders and files with the term '$term' in current directory will be deleted"
                $reply = Read-Host -Prompt "Continue?[y/n]"
if ( $reply -match "[yY]" ) { 
        $verbosity = Read-Host -Prompt "verbose? [y/n]"
if ( $verbosity -match "[yY]" ) { 
       
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "$term" -Directory | remove-item -Recurse -Verbose -Force
}
if ( $verbosity -match "[nN]" ) { 
       
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "$term" -Directory | Where-Object { Write-Progress "Deleting  $($_.Fullname)"; $true } | remove-item -Recurse -Force
}
}
}
```

if someone wants to further refine this to provide a ticker if a folder is taking a long time or some other aspect to make this a bit cleaner that would be great, if @spikey_richie wants to post this as an answer ill remove this one and accept theirs

Comment: No no, it's your answer, and you worked it out for yourself. Kudos to you :)